# surfaceTexture must not be null

Tags: java, android

I try to play some videos. But as soon as I reproduce the first video gets an error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
> ComponentInfo{cpm.example.advplayer/com.example.advplayer.ui.MainActivity}:
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: surfaceTexture must not be null

I write In `playerSetup()` method:

```java
public void playerSetup(Video video) {
    try {
        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(Application.video_path + video.getName());
        mMediaPlayer.setSurface(new Surface(savedSurfaceTexture));
        mMediaPlayer.prepare();
        mMediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(this);
        mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        adjustAspectRatio(mMediaPlayer.getVideoWidth(), mMediaPlayer.getVideoHeight());
        mMediaPlayer.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and

```java
@Override
public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int i, int i1) {
    savedSurfaceTexture = surfaceTexture;
}
```

in `onSurfaceTextureAvailable()` override method

How to make so, that you can play videos and `TextureView` will not be null?

Comment: Any updates on this?